# Advice on best remote control solution for Ubuntu from Windows

Tags: 14.04, remote-desktop, 16.04

I have a laptop which is running Ubuntu 14.04 (will switch to 16.04 tomorrow). I use this laptop for university, which consists of programming and database management (Oracle). Seeing as the laptop is the only place where I am using Linux, I try to work on my laptop as much as I can (especially for homework).

So, to the point: I want to control my Ubuntu laptop from my desktop at home. Both laptop and desktop are on the same network, so LAN remote control would be possible (if it exists). I care about a few things, listed below in **order of priority**:

- Low latency, lag-free
- Able to use my two monitors that I have on my desktop
- Full-screen usage, without any silly borders
- Audio optional, but would be nice to have if it's high quality

Could you, experienced Linux users, give any recommendations as to what remote-control program I want to use that fits my criteria?

I don't mind paying for it!

Answer (score 0):

One option i can recommend is Teamviewer which is free for personal use, easy to set up, avaiable for a lot of platforms.

[Link to developer website](https://www.teamviewer.com).

Comment: I have used TeamViewer for Windows to Windows remote control, but I have always found a noticeable lag. Do you think this will still persist if it's Windows to Ubuntu?

Comment: not really sure in my case i can live with that little bit of latency. I think its dependent on the machine power you have, and your internet connection, since its still goes over the teamviewer server even if youre in local network.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I honestly want the least bit possible latency possible. Also a bit of a shame that it will go through Teamviewer Servers even if it's just local.